# Execute commands from shell script fails

Tags: shell

I'm trying read a file which contains lines like this:

```
 Run COMMAND with options "OPTIONS" and arguments "ARGUMENTS"
```

Then I want to execute this command with given options and arguments. For example I'd like to execute these commands:

```
 Run pwd with options "" and arguments ""
 Run ls with options "-al" and arguments "$HOME"
 Run ls with options "-al" and arguments "Example: \"strange folder name\""
```

This is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
 COMMAND=$(echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f 2)
 OPTIONS=$(echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f 5 | tr -d '"')
 ARGUMENTS=$(echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f 8)

 $COMMAND $OPTIONS $ARGUMENTS
 done <$1
```

First example is working as it should, second one is giving me error `ls: cannot access $HOME: No such file or directory'` and third one is not storing the name of the folder to `$ARGUMENTS` correctly.

Comment: Don't use `cut` like that.  Your code is equivalent to `while read -r a COMMAND b c OPTIONS d e ARGUMENTS; ... done`  (except that this also assigns variabls `a`, `b`, and `c`.)  Let read parse the fields.

Comment: The suggestion from @WilliamPursell is a better way to go. To make the code even more readable and self-documenting, you can replace the unneeded variables with a variable named ignore `while read -r ignore COMMAND ignore ignore OPTIONS ignore ignore ARGUMENTS; ... done`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> second one is giving me error ls: cannot access $HOME: No such file or directory'

This is because the folder named `$HOME` does not exist. I am not talking about the value of `$HOME` variable, but the string literal. The shell does not execute the parameter expansion in your situation.

> third one is not storing the name of the folder to $ARGUMENTS correctly

This is because `-f 8` only extract column 8, try `-f 8-` to extract the 8th column and all the others until the end of line.

You can give a try to this version below:

```
while read -r line; do
  COMMAND=$(printf "%s" "${line}" | cut -d" " -f 2)
  OPTIONS=$(printf "%s" "${line}" | cut -d" " -f 5 | tr -d '"')
  ARGUMENTS=$(printf "%s" "${line}" | cut -d" " -f 8-)
  $COMMAND $OPTIONS "$(eval printf \"%s\" "$ARGUMENTS")"
done < "${1}"
```

The `eval` is a shell built-in command which is used to enable parameter expansion of `ARGUMENTS`, if applicable.

I have to warn you that the `eval` is usualy say risky to use.